# EXT JS 6 And SenchaTouchV2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, indexeddb, extjs6

I saw that very recently, Sencha Touch merged with ExtJS becoming ext-Js6 . It seems that there will be no longer update of senchaV2 ? Ad now that's better to use extJS6 than Sencha ?

I suppose that, all the features present in sencha V2 are still present in extJS6, so that I can migrate my projects without problems ? Is there still the comptability between ExtJS6 and indexedDB which was present in Sencha ?

Thank's for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExtJS 6 indeed merges the original ExtJS with Sencha Touch. If you were using Sencha CMD in your touch project, then you should be able to upgrade it to Extjs using [this guide](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/upgrades_migrations/modern_upgrade_guide.html).
Please note, that ExtJS now has the so-called toolkits. The classic toolkit is basically the original ExtJS and the modern toolkit is the successor to Sencha Touch.

Comment: Ok, with other research this week-end, that's indeed what I concluded ! Just another question : is ExtJS 6 responsive ? (like this link suppose it : https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/application_architecture/developing_for_multiple_screens_and_environments.html

Comment: I suppose it is. You have two options: you can either create an app using only the modern toolkit, this way your app will be responsive, or you can use both the modern and the classic toolkit. If you choose the second option, then you have to write some code twice (usually the views), but they will look better on a computer. First I would go using only the modern toolkit, it's a whole lot easier, and then when you get the hang of it you could add the classic toolkit for the desktop clients.